# C++ singleton pattern using boost::call_once

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, singleton

Singletons in C++ (at least prior C++11 AFAIK) can be a nightmare. With the whole static initialisation order fiasco. But boost::call_once seems to offer a robust way to implement singletons. I've tried to come up with an easy to use idiom I'd like to share for some critical feedback, hope I haven't been completely foolish :)

```
// Usage:
// You can make anything with a public or protected ctor a singleton.
//
// class A
// {
// public:
//     ~A();
// public:
//     // Optional, shorter to type
//     static A& Instance() { return Singleton<A>::Instance(); }
//     void foo();
//
// protected:
//     explicit A(); // Can't be private, but can be public, protected is recommended.
// };
//
// Singleton<A>::Instance().foo();
// A::Instance().foo();
//
template< class T >
class Singleton : public T // inerits from T so we can access the protected constructor.
{
public:
    virtual ~Singleton() {}

public:
    static T& Instance();

private:
    static boost::once_flag s_onceFlag;
    // We use a raw pointer to avoid dynamic initialisation. If something that
    // has a constructor (eg, shared_ptr ) then the dynamically initialised ctor
    // may get called after the call once function is called (if the call once function
    // is statically invoked before main). Then the instance pointer will be overwritten.
    // Using a zero initialised pointer avoids this problem.
    static T* s_instance;

private:
    static void Init();

private:
    explicit Singleton() {} // Used only to allow access to the protected ctor in base.
};



template< class T >
boost::once_flag Singleton<T>::s_onceFlag = BOOST_ONCE_INIT; // zero initialised variable, no order o initialisation shananigans

template< class T >
T* Singleton<T>::s_instance = 0;

template< class T >
void Singleton<T>::Init()
{
    static Singleton<T> instance; // static local variable is thread safe since this function is called once only.
    s_instance = &instance;
}


template< class T >
T& Singleton<T>::Instance()
{
    boost::call_once( s_onceFlag, Init );

    return *s_instance;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this should be on CodeReview.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To be fair, I expect that `call_once` is a threading specific version of something that can already been had in c++11 using just a function local static initializer:

  ```
  template< class T >
  T& Singleton<T>::Instance()
  {
      static bool const init = [] () -> bool { Init(); return true; }();

      return *s_instance;
  }
  ```

  The initializer is guaranteed not to race (in the language specification).

  Worst case behaviour is when the initializer throws: the exception will propagate out of the `Instance()` method but next time will try to initialize again, because the specification deems the variable to have "not been initialized" when the initializer expression throws.
- If in fact you "need" a thread-aware singleton (e.g. instance per thread), then you may want the `thread_local` keyword, with largely the same semantics.

Comment: Agree, using C++11 would be much cleaner.

Comment: @flux Oh. I got the impression you were using C++11 (you mention the history, and have tagged as [tag:c++11])

Comment: Sorry about that, C++11 was one of the recommended tags so I put it in there.